# Firefox 4 stores passwords, but suddenly forgot that it did?

Tags: filesystem, firefox

I am using firefox 4 as my default browser, but this is probably file system related. I will describe the problem and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction?

Today I was using the browser as normal, all sign ins worked as usual, everything was normal. Then when I got back home tonight and opened it, none of my saved usernames/passwords would autofill/auto-signin anymore. I am guessing this must be something filesystem related, and it only happened this one time seemingly at random, so I don't think it is a firefox 4 bug. In fact, I think it might be something to do with suspending the system before I left? Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is this related to Firefox Sync? If not, check that Firefox didn't somehow create a new profile here.

Comment: No it has not created a new profile and I don't use sync. That's why I think it might be filesystem related :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how it seems to have been fixed, so I'm not sure if it was a bug in a nightly build? Whatever the case is, it seems fixed for most websites now.